# How to prevent exceeding the parent's boundary?

Tags: html, css

I have data inside of divs:

```
-------------------------------------
| ----------   ------------------   |
| | Pane L |   |   D A T A      |   |
| |        |   |                |   |
| |        |   |                |   |
| |        |   |                |   |
| ----------   |                |   |
|              -----------------|   |
-------------------------------------
```

Parent's is determined based on size of "Data" panel.

In case if Pane L is TOO long (longer than Data) then it exceeds the boundary of its parent and doesn't pull parents boundary...

```
-------------------------------------
| ----------   ------------------   |
| | Pane L |   |   D A T A      |   |
| |        |   |                |   |
| |        |   |                |   |
| |        |   |                |   |
| |        |   -----------------|   |
--|        |-------------------------
  |        |
  ----------
```

CSS Style of "Pane L" among others contain: "float: left"

"Data" contains: "position: relative"

How to prevent Pane L exceeding the boundary of the parent?

I know there is something wrong with my CSS formatting, but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Any ideas are welcome!

EDIT: I've put solution recommended by rbighne, but it has side effect: empty space right from DATA panel and between Data and PaneL become squizzed... is there any solution that doesn't have any horizontal impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

```
.parent:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

(Assuming that the parent has class `parent` of course), this will make sure that Pane L pushes the bottom of the parent down until the parent is only as tall as Pane L.

Comment: That actually has a side effect... Earlier my "parent was full screen width, now it squizzes to the border of Data on the right side... Do you know how to change ':after' to work on the bottom side of the borders, not on the left and right?

Comment: @Budda I don't understand, what do you mean by "squizzes"? Do you mean that the parent collapses (has no width anymore)? That sounds strange.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't put ":after" selector. Works in full now

Answer (score 0):

You should use `overflow: hidden` on the parent container, but that will also cut off the longer content inside the pane L. Use `overflow-y: scroll` to allow the contents to scroll inside.